# Docker Hub + Travis-ci: como gerar uma description automática?

Tags: docker, integração-contínua, travis-ci

Venho batalhando já a 9 horas para conseguir fazer uma integração continua entre **Github** > **Travis-ci** e **Docker hub**. Até aqui já consegui atingir o seguinte objetivo: aplico um push para o Github, neste momento o Travis-ci "captura o código" e inicia a geração da build, correndo tudo bem faz o deploy no Docker hub...

Minha dificuldade está em gerar automaticamente o **Short Description** e **Full Description** no Docker Hub. Quando eu utilizava o recurso de compilação automático do próprio Docker hub, o README.md é puxado do Github para assumir a posição de Full Description, porém, devido minha nova abordagem com Travis-ci não estou utilizando a compilação automática do Docker hub.

Alguma ideia de como conseguir preencher esses dois campos com deploy via Travis-ci?

Segue abaixo o esqueleto do travis.yml (sei que está bem básico, mas meu objetivo inicial é vencer as etapas acima).

.travis.ym

```
language: bash
services: docker

env:
  - VERSION=7.2 VARIANT=stretch/apache

before_script:
  - env | sort
  - cd "$VERSION/$VARIANT"
  - SUBVARIANT="${VARIANT#*/}"
  - BASE_NAME_REPOSITORY=fabiojanio/php
  - IMAGE_NAME="${BASE_NAME_REPOSITORY}-${SUBVARIANT}"
  - IMAGE_FULL_VERSION="${BASE_NAME_REPOSITORY}-${SUBVARIANT}:${VERSION}-${VARIANT%/*}"
  - IMAGE_LATEST_VERSION="${BASE_NAME_REPOSITORY}-${SUBVARIANT}:latest"

script:
  - docker build -t "${IMAGE_LATEST_VERSION}" .

after_script:
  - docker images

before_deploy:
  - echo "${DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD}" | docker login --username "${DOCKER_HUB_USER}" --password-stdin

deploy:
  provider: script
  script: docker push "${IMAGE_LATEST_VERSION}"
  on:
    branch: master
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710513. Por curisiodade, por não continuar no _automated build_ do hub, está fazendo algum SCM pelo travis, algo do tipo?

Comment: @BrunoCésar estou utilizando o Travis-ci no processo, devido minha abordagem tive que tirar do automated build, inicialmente minha abordagem está bem simples, porém, dentro do escopo do Travis-ci ainda irei adicionar algumas etapas extras. Veja: https://www.github.com/docker-sources